# Can't download attachments in Yahoo. Yellow task will not show

Tags: windows-7, email

I'm using Yahoo for mail. When downloading attachment will get a yellow bar pop up that will ask where to save the file. I upgrades to MSE11. Using Windows 7.

Comment: I assume MSE11 means Internet Explorer 11? Does it still work in IE10 (IE11 has a compatability mode)?  Does it work in another browser

Comment: Hi Dave, i was able to download attachments on When using Explorer 10. Same thing happens with Chrome. Pls. Advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, then go to Tools and then Compatibility View settings.

Enter the name of the URL and try again.

Or, press F12 to get up the developer mode where you can set the document mode to previous versions.